# How do I pass user input data from page to page in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I am writing an app in Flutter and am trying to do a 2 page sign up process. Page 1 is their email, password and repeat password, and Page 2 is additional details about them for their account. This is part of a personal project.

I am trying to pass the data from the first sign up page, to the second. Once the user fills out the second page and presses sign up. The data is then collated and a FirebaseUser is created in Authentication and in the FireStore database.

a) Is this the right way to do it? AKA passing data from one page to the other. Then completing signup then, but if a user exists before completing second page then they have not created an account.

b) Should I instead just be adding information on the second page to the account created on the first? To me this makes sense, but I'm thinking in terms of usability, a user who doesn't complete the full sign up process, likely did not want an account set up for them.

I have tried countless tutorials on passing data from one page to another, however I always get errors relating to invalid constructor names, to const errors, or I go down a rabbit hole of just creating new objects and passing things along.

Signup.dart (Page 1)

```
try {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
            .then((user) => {
              Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.user.uid).setData({"email": _email, "password": _password}),
            });
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ExtraSignUpInfo()));
```

ExtraSignUpInfo.dart (Page 2)

```
class ExtraSignUpInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExtraSignUpInfoState createState() => _ExtraSignUpInfoState();
}

class _ExtraSignUpInfoState extends State<ExtraSignUpInfo> {
  String _name;
  String _company;
  String _jobTitle;
  String _teamName;
  String _industry;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

I want the user just created to be sent to ExtraSignUpInfo() page, so then the email and password can be created later after ExtraSignUpInfo() page form fields are filled in.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to pass the parameters using arguments and sending it with the named route call to the navigator, see this example on cookbook:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

1) In the second screen you have to create the ScreenArguments class like this:

```dart
class ScreenArguments {
  final String email;
  final String password;

  ScreenArguments(this.email, this.password);
}
```

2) Initiate the vars on second screen itself:

```dart
  String email;
  String password;
```

3) Call the navigator from a button(for example) on the first screen sending the values:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/secondScreen", arguments: email, password)
```

*Add the named route to your main.dart for this to work.

4) Use the values sent from screen1 to screen2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah perfect okay. I had something similar but not quite this simple and easy. I hadn't even thought of `pushNamed()`. I had created a class, but always with some error of some sort. I'll let you know how this goes.

Comment: Ok, let me know if it worked. That's the Flutter way, to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using a [stepper widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) where you collect the email, password, etc. on successive steps in sort of a form "wizard." There are many variants (Google 'stepper widget').

Here is a very basic setup adding a `TextFormField` you can use and add validation to:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepperForm extends StatefulWidget {
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {}

  @override
  _StepperFormState createState() => _StepperFormState();
}

class _StepperFormState extends State<StepperForm> {
  ///Stepper variables and functions
  //declare the currentStep (starting point) as an int 0
  int _currentStep = 0;

  //Create a list of steps. Use TextFormFields for the email/password. Add validation if needed.
  List<Step> _myStepperForm() {
    List<Step> _steps = [
      Step(
        title: Text("Enter Your Email"),
        //state: StepState.complete,
        isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
        content: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Email',
            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          validator: (value) =>
          value.isNotEmpty ? null : 'email can\'t be empty',
          //Additional validation code as needed
        ),
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text("Second"),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 1,
        content: Text("My Second Example"),
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text("Third"),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 2,
        content: Text("My Third Example"),
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text("Fourth"),
        isActive: _currentStep >= 3,
        content: Text("My Fourth Example"),
      ),
    ];
    return _steps;
  }

  //Create function for continue button
  onStepContinue() {
    setState(() {
      if (this._currentStep < this._myStepperForm().length - 1) {
        this._currentStep = this._currentStep + 1;
      } else {
        //Completion Code
        print('The form is complete.');
      }
    });
  }

  //create cancel function
  onStepCancel() {
    setState(() {
      if (this._currentStep > 0) {
        this._currentStep = this._currentStep - 1;
      } else {
        this._currentStep = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  //Create the Stepper Widget
  Widget _stepperWidget() => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        child: Stepper(
          //type: StepperType.horizontal,
          currentStep: this._currentStep,
          steps: _myStepperForm(),
          onStepCancel: onStepCancel,
          onStepContinue: onStepContinue,
          onStepTapped: (step) {
            setState(() {
              this._currentStep = step;
            });
          },
        ),
      );

 //Call Stepper Function in Scaffold. SingleChildScrollView helps with different screen sizes 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Stepper Form'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _stepperWidget(),
            SizedBox(height: 600)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you so much for this! I will certainly look this up and can tell from the code this might be exactly what I am looking for!