# How to get the object from API and update it in flutter

Tags: api, flutter

I am developing a registration screen in flutter when user signup with their detail the id will autogenerated from API i want to use the id for next page for updating the rest of user details,

I got the response from API in signup but I don't know how to take the specific object from response and used into another page then update the user details. please help me for this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702575/how-do-i-pass-user-input-data-from-page-to-page-in-flutter for one (of many) approaches

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i got it right without an example, you can store that value that you retrieve from APi and store in a variable and after simply pass that variable to another page with Navigator.push method.

```
onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondScreen(text: 'Json API',),
          ),
        );
      },
```

A more complex way store that value in system Preference and simply get access to those value from all the app. You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package